# how to use observables in html (angular)

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, pipe

I have a class that have an observable property

```
isPossible: Observable<boolean>;
```

and I want to use it from another class html file...so I understood I need to use something called pipe with async...I understand that this is how you use observables in html...but what I didnt understand is how I physically use it?

I have a simple ngIf condition and I want to use it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isPossible" layout="row" layout-align="center">
    <button md-raised-button class="md-raised md-primary" (click)="onPossibleClicked()">
      Select
    </button>
  </div>
```

how do I use this pipe so this html will work?

Answer (score 1):

> so I understood I need to use something called pipe with async

This is correct. You just need to alter your *ngIf like so:

```
<div *ngIf="isPossible | async" layout="row" layout-align="center">
```

By adding the `| async`, ng2 will use the observable (or promise) value instead of the direct value of `isPossible`.

Comment: Please help here (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege) in re here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095760/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege) and here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8393/primal-degenerate-optimal-dual-unique-optimal)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `async` pipe is for and you use it like

```
<div *ngIf="isPossible | async" layout="row" layout-align="center">
```

It subscribes to an `Observable` or `Promise` to get notified about emitted values.

More about available (built-in) pipes and how to use them https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html